# Storing member functions in a data structure

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class `Configuration` holding some floating-point parameters as key-value pairs in a map (keys are strings).
The user can set the parameters with a member function `Configuration::set(string, float)` and retrieve a value with the corresponding getter function.

As a remark, the user is me. This is just an helper class that my framework uses internally and is not exposed to the user.

The tricky part is that for some of these parameters the setter function must not just add the key-value pair into the map, but also do other simple operations. For instance, when the parameter "dt" is set by the user, the method should also compute and set the parameter "dtr" as `dtr = 1.f / dt`. This happens only for a small number of parameters, the vast majority does not need any special operation.

The parameters for which a special operation is required are known beforehand and can be safely hardcoded. In theory the set function can have an implementation like this (pseudo-code):

```
set(key, value):
    values.store(key, value)

    if key == "dt"
         values.store("dtr", 1/dt)
    else if key == "..."
         ...
    else if ...
         ...
    endif
end set
```

Now, this is quite ugly and makes the class less extensible than I wish (say that in future I might want to store other parameters than floating points). So I thought I could store a second map holding key-action pairs, where to every key there is a corresponding additional action that must be performed, stored as a function pointer. Then the pseudo-code for the setter would be:

```
set(key, value):
    values.store(key, value)

    if key in actions
        actions[key](value)
    endif
end set
```

All I need at this point is:

- To define member functions in the `Configuration` class to have the actions
- To register these member functions in a data structure such as `std::map`

The latter point is quite obscure to me. Is there a portable way of doing this?

There is another question with a similar problem: [Store Function Pointers to any Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988320/store-function-pointers-to-any-member-function). In both cases the problem can be addressed with the Observer pattern, but in my case this is quite overkill. All I need is a set of very small functions. I would prefer not polluting my code with a base class for actions and subclass it for all parameters that need a special action. At that point the original `if / else if` thing would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach like the following:

First define a variadic type to hold the *value*, for example:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, double> value_type;
```

Now define your map as:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<value_type, std::function<void(const value_type&)>> map_type;
```

Now when you have new types, expand the `value_type` to support it, the required *glue* code should be more manageable..